# Mixed Chart calculating difference between two bars - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, chart.js

I've been using Chart.JS a little more than a week, and I've faced some problems, but right now I'm really stuck.
[image]

I need to create something similar to this, there are 1 product(blue) value and the orange one is an estimate of its value on the next month. So what I need to do is basically `(((a — b) * 100) / a (or b I can't really remember))` and this as a label not actual data, and the result would be some percentage that would be used as a line on top of one product.
So far I got only this code, but it's not working like I need to.

```
          {
            type: "line",
            label: monthsLabels?.mesBaseLabel,
            data: [
              productsValues?.receitaLiquidaBase[0],
              productsValues?.receitaLiquidaOrcado[0],
            ],
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            type: "line",
            label: monthsLabels?.mesOrcadoLabel,
            data: [
              productsValues?.receitaLiquidaBase[0],
              productsValues?.receitaLiquidaOrcado[0],
            ],
            // data: productsValues?.receitaLiquidaOrcado,
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            label: monthsLabels?.mesBaseLabel,
            data: productsValues?.receitaLiquidaBase,
            // [
            //   productsValues?.receitaLiquidaBase[0],
            //   productsValues?.receitaLiquidaBase[1],
            // ],
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(42,62,176, 1)"],
            borderWidth: 4,
            datalabels: {
              // anchor: "end",
              // align: "top",
              font: {
                size: 10,
              },
              rotation: -90,
              color: "white",
              formatter: (value, context) => {
                // console.log(value);
                if (value !== 0) {
                  return value?.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,");
                } else {
                  return 0;
                }
              },
            },
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            label: monthsLabels?.mesOrcadoLabel,
            data: productsValues?.receitaLiquidaOrcado,
            backgroundColor: "orange",
            borderWidth: 4,
            datalabels: {
              // anchor: "end",
              // align: "top",
              font: {
                size: 10,
              },
              rotation: -90,
              color: "black",
              formatter: (value, context) => {
                // console.log(value);
                if (value !== 0) {
                  return value?.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,");
                } else {
                  return 0;
                }
              },
            },
          },
```

Objects on, `data` and `label` are an array of number coming from some fetching.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are best off using a custom inline plugin for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      customValue: {
        offset: 5,
        dash: [5, 15]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customValue',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx,
        data: {
          datasets
        },
        _metasets
      } = chart;

      datasets[1].data.forEach((dp, i) => {
        let increasePercent = dp * 100 / datasets[0].data[i] >= 100 ? Math.round((dp * 100 / datasets[0].data[i] - 100) * 100) / 100 : Math.round((100 - dp * 100 / datasets[0].data[i]) * 100) / 100 * -1;
        let barValue = `${increasePercent}%`;
        const lineHeight = ctx.measureText('M').width;
        const offset = opts.offset || 0;
        const dash = opts.dash || [];

        ctx.textAlign = 'center';

        ctx.fillText(barValue, _metasets[1].data[i].x, (_metasets[1].data[i].y - lineHeight * 1.5), _metasets[1].data[i].width);

        if (_metasets[0].data[i].y >= _metasets[1].data[i].y) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.setLineDash(dash);

          ctx.moveTo(_metasets[0].data[i].x, _metasets[0].data[i].y);
          ctx.lineTo(_metasets[0].data[i].x, _metasets[1].data[i].y - offset);
          ctx.lineTo(_metasets[1].data[i].x, _metasets[1].data[i].y - offset);
          ctx.stroke();
        } else {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.setLineDash(dash);

          ctx.moveTo(_metasets[0].data[i].x, _metasets[0].data[i].y - offset);
          ctx.lineTo(_metasets[1].data[i].x, _metasets[0].data[i].y - offset);
          ctx.lineTo(_metasets[1].data[i].x, _metasets[1].data[i].y - offset - lineHeight * 2);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      });
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, I just woke up, and it looks like this should be what I need to do. I'll put together my code later on.
Thanks, I didn't even know about the existence of this plugin.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks, this was exactly what I need to do, tbh without your help I would just do a different version of it, I would never get it right.